# Checking migrated solution into new version of TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I have recently migrated a number of apps created in Visual Studio versions 2005, 2008, and 2010 to VS2013. When I tried to check them into our TFS install, I was greeted with a message telling me that I needed to use a newer version (of TFS).

I contacted our server admin and got a share set up on a new version of tfs.

How the heck do I go about adding to the new TFS share? It is showing on the server (with the plus signs), but when I try to check-in the code, it complains at me telling me to first create a Team Project.

Do I need to create a blank Team project then copy all of my files in, or is there a shorter way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Which version are you coming from? Cab you use VSO instead as it sounds like your infrastructure is not uo to keeping your code secure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an existing TFS server then you should upgrade it rate than copy stuff to a new server. It sounds like your existing server is TFS 2008 so you would need to upgrade to 2012 and then to 2013. No big deal, just a little more rigmarole.

If you are set on just pushing your code to a new server I would instead recommend that you create an account with Visual Studio Online (http://tfs.visualstudio.com) and use that.

If you are just going to shove it in the new TFS 2013 server that your infrastructure guy knocked together then you will need to create a Team Project first.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181477.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the reply... Upgrading was not an option as many other groups in our company still use TFS2008. I just created a Team Project and then checked my changes into that.

Comment: You can upgrade to at least TFS 2012 and still fully support VS 2008. #noexcuses

Comment: Right... But I'm not in charge of where other group's in my company want to put their code repository. That's a much higher pay grade than mine. #notmakingexcuses